# Pandas resample doesn't return anything

Tags: python, pandas

I am learning to use pandas resample() function, however, the following code does not return anything as expected. I re-sampled the time series by day.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

range = pd.date_range('2015-01-01','2015-12-31',freq='15min')
df = pd.DataFrame(index = range)

df['speed'] = np.random.randint(low=0, high=60, size=len(df.index))
df['distance'] = df['speed'] * 0.25
df['cumulative_distance'] = df.distance.cumsum()

print df.head()

weekly_summary = pd.DataFrame()
weekly_summary['speed'] = df.speed.resample('D').mean()
weekly_summary['distance'] = df.distance.resample('D').sum()

print weekly_summary.head()
```

Output

```
                     speed  distance  cumulative_distance
2015-01-01 00:00:00     40     10.00                10.00
2015-01-01 00:15:00      6      1.50                11.50
2015-01-01 00:30:00     31      7.75                19.25
2015-01-01 00:45:00     41     10.25                29.50
2015-01-01 01:00:00     59     14.75                44.25

[5 rows x 3 columns]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [speed, distance]
Index: []

[0 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: this works for me, what version pandas are you using? Mine is 0.19.1, what maybe confusing it is that you initially create an empty df and then assign a new column, it's possible that this may fail in an older version as it's not enlarging the df

Comment: 0.13.1 is mine's version.

Comment: @daydayup You may want to update, many things in Pandas change over a few years' time :)

Comment: I see. thank you everybody for your help!

Comment: Try this: `weekly_summary = pd.DataFrame(df.speed.resample('D').mean())` so replace the empty df line and the subsequent line with what I suggested, this will create a df with the correct index and initial column, the subsequent assignments should then work

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your pandas version, how you will do this will vary.

In pandas 0.19.0, your code works as expected:

```
In [7]: pd.__version__
Out[7]: '0.19.0'

In [8]: df.speed.resample('D').mean().head()
Out[8]: 
2015-01-01    28.562500
2015-01-02    30.302083
2015-01-03    30.864583
2015-01-04    29.197917
2015-01-05    30.708333
Freq: D, Name: speed, dtype: float64
```

In older versions, your solution might not work but at least in 0.14.1, you can tweak it to do so:

```
>>> pd.__version__
'0.14.1'
>>> df.speed.resample('D').mean()
29.41087328767123
>>> df.speed.resample('D', how='mean').head()
2015-01-01    29.354167
2015-01-02    26.791667
2015-01-03    31.854167
2015-01-04    26.593750
2015-01-05    30.312500
Freq: D, Name: speed, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. have just upgraded to 19.0 to avoid the hassles.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an issue with old version of pandas, in newer versions it will enlarge the df when assigning a new column where the index is not the same shape. What should work is to not make an empty df and instead pass the initial call to `resample` as the data arg for the df ctor:

```
In [8]:
range = pd.date_range('2015-01-01','2015-12-31',freq='15min')
df = pd.DataFrame(index = range)
df['speed'] = np.random.randint(low=0, high=60, size=len(df.index))
df['distance'] = df['speed'] * 0.25
df['cumulative_distance'] = df.distance.cumsum()
print (df.head())
weekly_summary = pd.DataFrame(df.speed.resample('D').mean())
weekly_summary['distance'] = df.distance.resample('D').sum()
print( weekly_summary.head())

                     speed  distance  cumulative_distance
2015-01-01 00:00:00     28       7.0                  7.0
2015-01-01 00:15:00      8       2.0                  9.0
2015-01-01 00:30:00     10       2.5                 11.5
2015-01-01 00:45:00     56      14.0                 25.5
2015-01-01 01:00:00      6       1.5                 27.0
                speed  distance
2015-01-01  27.895833    669.50
2015-01-02  29.041667    697.00
2015-01-03  27.104167    650.50
2015-01-04  28.427083    682.25
2015-01-05  27.854167    668.50
```

Here I pass the call to `resample` as the data arg for the df ctor, this will take the index and column name and create a single column df:

```
weekly_summary = pd.DataFrame(df.speed.resample('D').mean())
```

then subsequent assignments should work as expected

Comment: Thank you for the help. have just upgraded to 19.0 to avoid the hassles.